# In a hypothesis test, what is preventing us from peeking and setting $H_0: \mu = \bar{x}$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval

In a hypothesis test, it seems that normally we first set the significance level $\alpha$ and then set the null hypothesis value, $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$, find the rejection region, then FINALLY introduce the observed data $X= x$, then see if the observed test statistic $T(x)$ falls into the rejection region.

What is preventing us from first "peeking" at the observed data, $x$, then setting $H_0: \mu = \bar{x}$ and achieving a rejection each time?

Comment: I think you might be thinking of this backwards. What kind of terrible hypothesis test would *reject* the hypothesis that $\mu = \bar{x}$? After all, in most cases, $\bar{x}$ is your best single estimate of $\mu$.

Comment: The hypothesized value for $\mu$ should be based on what makes sense as a null hypothesis for the problem.The sample mean is based on the randomly generated data.  Why would you want the null hypothesis to change if the observed data were different? We would never reject the null hypothesis if we did it your way as Kodiologist mentioned and usually the objective is to reject the null hypothesis.